# how to change player notification title and large icon in Media3 in android 11+?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-mediasession, android-media3

I using `MediaSessionService` from `Media3` to play audio in background.
I update player notification using `setMediaNotificationProvider`. but in android 11(API 30) and up, the title, content text, and large icon are not changing and showing default things related to audio file. is this a bug or am I missing some things?

```
val mediaNotificationProvider = object : MediaNotification.Provider{
    override fun createNotification(
        mediaSession: MediaSession,
        customLayout: ImmutableList<CommandButton>,
        actionFactory: MediaNotification.ActionFactory,
        onNotificationChangedCallback: MediaNotification.Provider.Callback
    ): MediaNotification {
        createMediaNotification(mediaSession)
        return MediaNotification(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
    }

    override fun handleCustomCommand(
        session: MediaSession,
        action: String,
        extras: Bundle
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}

private lateinit var notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder

fun  createMediaNotification(
    session: MediaSession,
) {
    notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context,
        NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID
    )
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
        .setContentTitle("test title")
        .setContentText("test text")
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.notification_large_icon))
        .setStyle(MediaStyleNotificationHelper.MediaStyle(session))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code was correct and the problem was only a bug in `Media3`.
by downgrading media3 from 1.0.1 to 1.0.0-beta03 my code works now!